# how to achieve string conversion of list of maps in java

Tags: java, json

How can i convert  JSON string  to format given below and back to JSON string.

```
List<Map<String, String>> variables =new ArrayList<>();
```

I tried searching for this. Only thing which i could find is converting list to array and then to string. But using

```
TypeA[] array = a.toArray(new TypeA[a.size()]);
```

does not seems feasible here.

Comment: What do you mean by "converting map to string"? I believe you're need some kind of serialization/deserialization here.

Comment: The "below" is **not** a string.

Comment: Do you mean like serialization to some Json/xml?

Comment: You could convert each map to a JSON object? `new JSONObject(map);`  And collect them all into a JSONArray

Comment: May be you can illustrate your expectation with an example

Comment: basically input is going to in JSON stringify form. I need to convert it to given format operate on it and give the result back in the json string form. I will update my question. sorry for missing this info

Comment: [google gson](https://github.com/google/gson) might be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Converting `List<Map<String,String>>` to JSON string :**

```
public String listmap_to_json_string(List<Map<String, String>> list)
{       
    JSONArray json_arr=new JSONArray();
    for (Map<String, String> map : list) {
        JSONObject json_obj=new JSONObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            try {
                json_obj.put(key,value);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                           
        }
        json_arr.put(json_obj);
    }
    return json_arr.toString();
}
```

Or simply using google gson library:

```
public String listmap_to_json_string(List<Map<String, String>> list){
    // Use toJson method to serialize list to Json
    return  new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(list);
}
```

**Converting JSON string to `List<Map<String,String>>`:**

```
public List<Map<String, String>> json_string_to_listmap(String json){   
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
    // Use fromJson method to deserialize json into an ArrayList of Map
    return gson.fromJson(json , type);
}
```

For more informations check this [link](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html).

Comment: great one.... i was looking for this API only. this gson is pretty awesome. thanks a lot... !!!

Comment: @user2696466 you are welcome. Do not forget to encourage me with the famous +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you should update your question to give more details. Meanwhile, with the current understanding I have from your post I would suggest you to look at ObjectMapper class from org.codehaus.jackson.map.

You will easily get a JSON converted in the type you want by using

```
// string in json format
String json;
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(json, TypeA.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code show how convert json string to type `List<Map<String,String>>`:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    TypeReference < List < Map < String, String >>> typeReference = new TypeReference < List < Map < String, String >>> () {

    };
    List < Map < String, String >> res = objectMapper.readValue("[{\"size\":\"100x200\"}]", typeReference);
    System.out.println("type: " + typeReference.getType());
    for (Map < String, String > map: res) {
        for (String key: map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + " : " + map.get(key));
        }
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```